# Closing multiple modals using one jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube, bootstrap-modal

I am making a website in which there are around 20 modals (bootstrap) on a single page. Each modal contains an iframe which plays a youtube video.

Till now, all I did was created all 20 modals with div #myModal1, #myModal2 ........... #myModal20.

Then, I looked for a javascript code which can stop a youtube video when I close the modal and found the jquery code (shown below)

```js
jQuery(".modal-backdrop, #myModal2 .close, #myModal2 .btn").on("click", function() {
        jQuery("#myModal2 iframe").attr("src", jQuery("#myModal2 iframe").attr("src"));
});
```

The above code stops the youtube video when I close the modal with div #myModal2.

Now, since there are 20 modals and I wrote the same code for all of them just changing #myModal3, #myModal4,...........and so on.

Can I do the same using for loop (I am new to this javascript) but I tried something and it is not working.

The code I wrote was:

```
for(i=1; i<21; i++) {

var modal = "#myModal"+i;

jQuery(".modal-backdrop, " + modal +" .close, " + modal +".btn").on("click", function() {
    jQuery(modal+" iframe").attr("src", jQuery(modal+" iframe").attr("src"));
});

}
```

It is not working.

Comment: It would be a simpler pattern to re-use the same modal repeatedly, just changing its content for each usage. This way as soon as the content is removed when the modal is closed, the video is automatically stopped.

Comment: I tried using the same modal (keeping div id as #myModal). The problem is that when I clicked on different buttons related to modal it showed the same video (video in first modal) in all the button clicks.

Comment: That would be a much better problem to solve than repeating the same code all throughout your site.

Comment: What I found out was each modal should have a unique id for it to show its content. So then, the javascript came into picture. And repetition of same js code began.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you do not need a for loop for this, just bind a click handler to `[id*='myModal']` which are all the elements having id starting with `myModal`

```
jQuery("[id*='myModal'] .close, [id*='myModal'] .btn").on("click", function() {
        var that = this;
        jQuery(that).find("iframe").attr("src", jQuery(that).find("iframe").attr("src"));
});
```

And now clicking on the backdrop should stop all the videos

```
jQuery(".modal-backdrop").on("click", function() {
            jQuery([id*='myModal']).find("iframe").attr("src", jQuery([id*='myModal']).find("iframe").attr("src"));
});
```

Why your code is not working because the value of `i` is constantly changing and is not preserved per click handler.

To make it work you should use **IIFE**.

Comment: I copied the above code in my js file but it is not working. Any idea why? Or shall I look into IIFE.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code a little bit by defining immediately-invoked function expression **IIFE**.

I had the jquery to stop the youtube video on clicking close button and just needed to input a variable which will work for all the modals so I added [id^='myModal] to the input that is *i* which the function takes to execute the code.

```
(function(i) {

    //Defining a variable "modal" equating it to "[id^='myModal']"
    //'i' will be any modal having id starting with **myModal**
    var modal = i;

    //Jquery to stop the youtube video 
    jQuery(".modal-backdrop, " + modal +" .close, " + modal +".btn").on("click", function() {
    jQuery(modal+" iframe").attr("src", jQuery(modal+" iframe").attr("src"));
});
}
("[id^='myModal']"));
```